# Inserting into Multiple Bookmark Locations - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am using an Excel macro where I am inserting the same text to several bookmarks in a Word doc. How can I do this by specifying the insert command once and apply it to all the bookmark locations?

Now I am doing the following for all bookmarks?

```
Dim monYear As String
monYear = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Now), "mmmm yyyy")


wdApp.Selection.GoTo what:=-1, Name:="Front_Page_Month_Year"
wdApp.Selection.TypeText monYear

wdApp.Selection.GoTo what:=-1, Name:="Page2_Month_Year"
wdApp.Selection.TypeText monYear
```

And on and on....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to use a single command to write to multiple bookmark locations. What you can do, however, is *reference* one bookmark location in order to display that bookmark's content in multiple locations.

Create the bookmark, then insert a *cross-reference* to it in each location where you want to display the bookmark contents. (Or create one cross-reference, then copy/paste to the other locations.)

A tip for your code: the approach you're using with the `Selection` object is not optimal. As in Excel, it's better to work with the object model, rather than rely on a Selection. Thus:

```
Dim doc as Word.Document
Set doc = wdApp.ActiveDocument 'Note: if you're opening a document, set in the Open method
doc.Bookmarks("Front_Page_Month_Year").Range.Text = monYear
'When you're done, update the REF fields (references)
doc.Fields.Update
```

Comment: What does `doc.Fields.Update` do?

Comment: And since I am programming in Excel VBE, the `Bookmarks` function doesn't work.

Comment: cross-references are maintained by REF field codes. Update forces the fields to update (think of it like forcing calculation in Excel). If you declare and instantiate `doc` as I show, then Bookmarks should work. If not, explain HOW it doesn't work - and it's not a function, it's a collection.

Comment: I have my Word variable as an instance of the Application object `(Word.Application)`.  I don't want to change it to `Word.Document`, how I can use Bookmarks this way?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't have both. It would certainly be more efficient, as well as more readable AND more reliable. But wdApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("name") is also possible.